# HTML Table Resets Inputs When Row is Added

Tags: html, input, html-table, row, reset

I am using the JQuery extension Chosen for a dropdown in a table.
I'm using Javascript to add rows to the table, but when I add a row the chosen box on the last row is the only one that works. To clarify, when I say they don't work, I mean they won't open or close (if they were open).

Here is the HTML of the table:

```
    <table id="entrytable">
        <tbody id="entrytbody">
            <tr>
                <th>Lot</th>
                <th>Time In</th>
                <th>Time Out</th>
                <th>Lot Condition</th>
                <th>Plowed</th>
                <th>Shovelled</th>
                <th>Salted</th>
                <th>People Who Helped You</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the code I'm using to add a row:

```
        var numRows = 0;
        function addRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById("entrytbody");
            table.innerHTML += "<tr><td><select id='lot" + numRows + "' name='lot" + numRows + "' data-placeholder='Choose a Lot...' class='chosen-select' required><option value=''></option><option value='United States'>United States</option><option value='United States'>aawsd</option><option value='United States'>hhe</option><option value='United States'>Ugfdh</option><option value='United States'>ffy</option><option value='United States'>uhg</option></select></td><td><input name='timein" + numRows + "' type='time' required></td><td><input name='timeout" + numRows + "' type='time' required></td><td><input name='condition" + numRows + "' type='text' required></td><td><input name='plowed" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'></td><td><input name='shovelled" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'></td><td><input name='salted" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'><input name='saltamount" + numRows + "' type='number' style='width: 40px;' min=0></td><td><input name='people" + numRows + "' type='text' required></td></tr>"
            $("#lot" + numRows).chosen();
            numRows++;
        }
        addRow();
```

When I make it so there are two rows on page load, both of them work. Also, when the call `$("#lot" + numRows).chosen();` is removed, the previous rows still don't work.

I've been trying to fix this problem for a few hours, and have also searched for a solution and still can't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying for a couple more hours, I gave up and removed the Chosen aspect of the dropdown menu and the regular dropdown would reset after adding a new row. Long story short, I fixed the problem by creating a table row through javascript and injecting the HTML into that, instead of straight to the table.

I'm not sure why it worked, but here is the edited code:

```
    var numRows = 0;
    function addRow() {
        var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        newRow.innerHTML += "<td><select id='lot" + numRows + "' name='lot" + numRows + "' data-placeholder='Choose a Lot...' class='chosen-select' required><option value=''></option><option value='United States'>United States</option><option value='United States'>aawsd</option><option value='United States'>hhe</option><option value='United States'>Ugfdh</option><option value='United States'>ffy</option><option value='United States'>uhg</option></select></td><td><input name='timein" + numRows + "' type='time' required></td><td><input name='timeout" + numRows + "' type='time' required></td><td><input name='condition" + numRows + "' type='text' required></td><td><input name='plowed" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'></td><td><input name='shovelled" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'></td><td><input name='salted" + numRows + "' type='checkbox'><input name='saltamount" + numRows + "' type='number' style='width: 40px;' min=0></td><td><input name='people" + numRows + "' type='text' required></td>"
        var table = document.getElementById("entrytbody");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        $("#lot" + numRows).chosen();
        numRows++;
    }
    addRow();
```

I also edited the tags to fit the real problem that was happening